# ShopWare: extending mutations and state of page components

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

Can the vuex state(mutations and getters) of any page such as sw-product-detail be extended? I'm trying to add mutation for product extensions(product.extension.myCustomEntity) but so far I have not found any docs covering this topic or other components doing a similar behavior.

Comment: Is this about Shopware PWA or the admin panel? What did you try so far?

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your continuous help. This was about extending setters in the admin panel in the product settings view. There was two solutions, the first one is by overriding the vuex module register in the beforeCreated life cycle method but it was discouraged by one of my colleagues. The other solution which we went by is by creating a new vuex module then assign its state to the original module letting vue reactivity handle the work

Comment: @Alex, but we are still trying to figure out the correct way to do so, I have one more test to conduct which is by overriding(extending) the state file it self by multiple dummy plugins and see if all of changes are correctly reflecting

Answer (score 2):

We did not implement a way to extend vuex states. There are several reasons for this, but the most important one is that only one source should determine how the state looks. If you imagine multiple extensions fiddling around with the state like you mentioned you are doing now, things will break.